# Strapi changing mongo uri has no effect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi

I've created a Strapi cms instance connecting to a remote Atlas db.
Now I have to create some more environments so I'm trying to change the development database uri.
but changing the uri in config/environments/development/database.json has. no effect.
I'm:

1. Changing the value
2. Running strapi build
3. Running strapi develop

all the old content is still there

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is stored in the database, model settings are stored in files

Comment: I'm trying to change the database uri in the environment file

Answer (score 0):

You should change the values of the file:

```
Path: ./config/environments/(development|production)/database.json.
```

example:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "ds125048.mlab.com",
        "port": "25048",
        "database": "myapp-development",
        "username": "myusername",
        "password": "mypassword"
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "myapp-development",
        "ssl": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then re-deploy to your app

[more details](https://strapi.io/blog/using-mlab-with-strapi)